# how to know the find_package name in cmake?

Tags: c++, api, cmake

I am had been forced to cmake and I am working with a lot of external APIs like OpenGL,Vulken and GLFW .. etc. I was using Makefiles very happily but then ....

now each time i had to use find_package for these API.I normaly google and Copy past it. But in practical life , How should I know what is name of that package ? like for OpenGL I had to use `find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)` . How should I know it OpenGL and not OPENGL or opengl ? is there any convention ?

please help as I am noob and I am so tried with this cmake :(

Comment: You can go into cmake install dir (such as `C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.10\Modules`) and see the list of available `find_xxx.cmake` scripts there. Note that you will also need to read scripts of interest to figure out what they do and which usable global variables they create.

Answer (score 0):

CMake stock modules are listed in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-modules.7.html). For third-party packages consult the list of files installed by it.